# scrlttr2: make second page footer match first page footer

Tags: header-footer, scrlttr2

I'm trying do my cover letter in `scrlttr2`. I'm working from a template which I found online and I want the same footer for the second page as for the first. I really have no idea how to do this and all I get is "page 2" in the footer section of my second page. The template, extended to be a two page letter can be found below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Short Stylish Cover Letter](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/short-stylish-cover-letter)

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{fontspec} % Allows font customization
\usepackage{marvosym} % Allows the use of symbols
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Required to compile in Windows

\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Removes all indentation from paragraphs

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont {Garamond} % Main document font
\setsansfont {Garamond} % Used in the from address line above the to address

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{12.5}{17}\selectfont} % Sets the font size and leading
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  PERSONAL INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setkomavar{fromname}{John Smith} % Your name
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{123 Broadway\\City\\Country} % Your address
\setkomavar{fromphone}{(000) 111-1111} % Your phone number
\setkomavar{fromemail}{john@smith.com} % Your email address
\setkomavar{place}{} % City written before the date, put your city here if you want this
\setkomavar{signature}{John Smith} % Your name as you want it to appear in the signature

% These are not used in this document, uncomment if you would like to use them and refer to them as \usekomavar{name}
%\setkomavar{fromfax}{+1 (1)23 456789} % Your fax number
%\setkomavar{fromurl}{http://www.johnsmith.com} % Your personal website
%\setkomavar{frombank}{Postbank 9307157}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  HEADER SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firsthead{
\centering
{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}\fontsize{36}{36}\selectfont\scshape \usekomavar{fromname}}\\[5mm]
\fontsize{21}{21}\selectfont\scshape Programmer at Initech } % Your current job title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  FOOTER SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstfoot{
\centering
\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}\scshape
{
\renewcommand{\\}{\ {\large\textperiodcentered}\ }
\usekomavar{fromaddress}
}\\
{\Large\Letter} \usekomavar{fromemail} \ {\Large\Telefon} \usekomavar{fromphone} % If you want your fax number or website URL showing, add it here; you may need to play around with spacing
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% COVER LETTER CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{letter}{ % Address of the company you are applying to
HR Dept. --- Corporation\\
123 Pleasant Lane\\
12345 City, State
}

\setkomavar{subject}{Cover Letter} % This is the bold text saying 'Cover Letter', remove it if you don't like it

\opening{Dear Recruiter,}

PARAGRAPH ONE: State the reason for the letter, name the position or type of work you are applying for and identify the source from which you learned of the opening.\\

PARAGRAPH TWO: Indicate why you are interested in the position, the company, its products, services - above all, stress what you can do for the employer. If you are a recent graduate, explain how your academic background makes you a qualified candidate for the position. If you have practical work experience, point out specific achievements or unique qualifications. Try not to repeat the same information the reader will find in the resume. The purpose of this section is to strengthen your resume by providing details which bring your experiences to life.\\

PARAGRAPH TWO: Indicate why you are interested in the position, the company, its products, services - above all, stress what you can do for the employer. If you are a recent graduate, explain how your academic background makes you a qualified candidate for the position. If you have practical work experience, point out specific achievements or unique qualifications. Try not to repeat the same information the reader will find in the resume. The purpose of this section is to strengthen your resume by providing details which bring your experiences to life.\\

PARAGRAPH TWO: Indicate why you are interested in the position, the company, its products, services - above all, stress what you can do for the employer. If you are a recent graduate, explain how your academic background makes you a qualified candidate for the position. If you have practical work experience, point out specific achievements or unique qualifications. Try not to repeat the same information the reader will find in the resume. The purpose of this section is to strengthen your resume by providing details which bring your experiences to life.\\

PARAGRAPH THREE: Request a personal interview and indicate your flexibility as to the time and place. Repeat your phone number in the letter. End the letter by thanking the employer for taking the time to consider your credentials.\\

Sincerely yours, \\ \\ \\
\usekomavar{signature}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

**Update** (package `scrlayer-scrpage` and page style `plain` on all pages)

It is also possible to remove the `firstfoot` and to use page style `plain` with the same footer on all pages. The footer layers can be shifted down so that they are at the same vertical position as the `firstfoot` would be. Note that `firsthead` still can be used.

```latex
\documentclass[
  symbolicnames,
  firstfoot=false,% disable firstfoot
  footlines=2% or footheight=29pt
  ]{scrlttr2}
%\providecommand*\Ifstrstart{\ifstrstart}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setkomavar{fromname}{John Smith}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{123 Broadway\\City\\Country}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{(000) 111-1111}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{john@smith.com}
\setkomavar{place}{}
\setkomavar{signature}{John Smith}
\setkomavar{subject}{Cover Letter}

\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
    \centering{\Huge\scshape\usekomavar{fromname}\par%
}%
    {\Large\scshape Application\par}%
}

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\centering%
{%
\renewcommand{\\}{~{\large\textperiodcentered}~}%
\usekomavar{fromaddress}%
}\\%
\usekomavar*{fromemail}\usekomavar{fromemail}\quad\usekomavar*{fromphone}\usekomavar{fromphone}%
}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\KOMAoptions{footwidth=\useplength{firstfootwidth}}
\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{plain.scrheadings}{%
  \Ifstrstart{#1}{plain.scrheadings.foot}{%
    \ModifyLayer[
      voffset=\useplength{firstfootvpos}
    ]{#1}
  }{}
}% shift the footer down
\ModifyLayer[
  addvoffset=-1ex
]{plain.scrheadings.foot.above.line}% shift the footsepline up
\addtokomafont{pagefoot}{\normalfont}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot*{\usekomavar{firstfoot}}

\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\opening{\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{}% <- first pages will have pagestyle plain too

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{%
HR Dept. --- Corporation\\%
123 Pleasant Lane\\%
12345 City, State%
}

\opening{Dear Recruiter,}\the\baselineskip
\blindtext[2]

\blindtext

\blindtext[3]
\closing{See you on monday}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: screenshot]

---

**Original answer**

If the footer on the second page should be at the same position as the footer on the first page you can load the package `scrlayer` and define your own pagestyle:

```
\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  align=tl,
  hoffset=\dimexpr.5\paperwidth-.5\useplength{firstfootwidth}\relax,
  voffset=\useplength{firstfootvpos},
  width=\useplength{firstfootwidth},
  height=\dimexpr\paperheight-\useplength{firstfootvpos},
  foreground,
  contents={\parbox{\layerwidth}{\usekomavar{firstfoot}}}
]{myfoot.fg}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{myletter}{myfoot.fg}
\pagestyle{myletter}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[symbolicnames]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{blindtext} 

\setkomavar{fromname}{John Smith}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{123 Broadway\\City\\Country}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{(000) 111-1111}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{john@smith.com}
\setkomavar{place}{}
\setkomavar{signature}{John Smith}
\setkomavar{subject}{Cover Letter}

\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
    \centering{\Huge\scshape\usekomavar{fromname}\par%
}%
    {\Large\scshape Application\par}%
}

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\centering%
{%
\renewcommand{\\}{~{\large\textperiodcentered}~}%
\usekomavar{fromaddress}%
}\\%
\usekomavar*{fromemail}\usekomavar{fromemail}\quad\usekomavar*{fromphone}\usekomavar{fromphone}%
}

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  align=tl,
  hoffset=\dimexpr.5\paperwidth-.5\useplength{firstfootwidth}\relax,
  voffset=\useplength{firstfootvpos},
  width=\useplength{firstfootwidth},
  height=\dimexpr\paperheight-\useplength{firstfootvpos},
  foreground,
  contents={\parbox{\layerwidth}{\usekomavar{firstfoot}}}
]{myfoot.fg}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{myletter}{myfoot.fg}
\pagestyle{myletter}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{%
HR Dept. --- Corporation\\%
123 Pleasant Lane\\%
12345 City, State%
}

\opening{Dear Recruiter,}
\blindtext[2]

\blindtext

\blindtext[3]
\closing{See you on monday}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, i have to say that i do not recommend using the templated linked in the question. It uses obsolete options and does really weird stuff most of the time.

We simply use the variable `firstfoot` when setting the variable `nextfoot`. To make this work properly, we have to tweak the first foot a bit as well, namely putting all in a parbox.

It should be noted, that this only works, if the pagestyle `headings` is active.

```
\documentclass[symbolicnames]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\pagestyle{headings}

\setkomavar{fromname}{John Smith}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{123 Broadway\\City\\Country}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{(000) 111-1111}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{john@smith.com}
\setkomavar{place}{}
\setkomavar{signature}{John Smith}
\setkomavar{subject}{Cover Letter}

\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
    \centering{\Huge\scshape\usekomavar{fromname}\par%
}%
    {\Large\scshape Application\par}%
}

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\centering%
{%
\renewcommand{\\}{~{\large\textperiodcentered}~}%
\usekomavar{fromaddress}%
}\\%
\usekomavar*{fromemail}\usekomavar{fromemail}\quad\usekomavar*{fromphone}\usekomavar{fromphone}%
}%
}
%Simply reusing the variable
\setkomavar{nextfoot}{\usekomavar{firstfoot}}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{%
HR Dept. --- Corporation\\%
123 Pleasant Lane\\%
12345 City, State%
}

\opening{Dear Recruiter,}
\blindtext[2]

\blindtext

\blindtext[3]
\closing{See you on monday}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, `\setkomavar{nextfoot}{\usekomavar{firstfoot}}` is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!