# scrlttr2 - set nextfoot set to same as firstfoot

Tags: header-footer, scrlttr2

I am tryint to get the same footer on all pages as the first page in scrlttr2. After some googling I came up with this code:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\begin{document}

\firstfoot{\footnotesize%
    \rule[3pt]{\textwidth}{.4pt} \\
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}% 
        Super Man\\
        Super Straße 30\\
        12345 Super Town
    \end{tabular}%
    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
        Telefon: +49123456789\\
        super.man@gmail.com\\
    \end{tabular}%
        \hfill
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
            Bankverbindung: \\
            IBAN: DEXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XX\\
            BIC: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
        \end{tabular}%
}%
\addtokomafont{pagefoot}{\normalfont}
\pagestyle{headings}
\nextfoot{\usekomavar{firstfoot}}

\begin{letter}{Addr}
\opening{}
% You have to fill enough text to get to the second page
\closing{}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

You have to fill the comment with lorem ispum or something else to generate a second page!

But I have the following problems:

1. `\pagestyle{headings}` also inserts the headers on the next page. I do not want that!
2. The footer on the next page is not rendered correctly. It looks like this:

[image: Wrong footer]

while on the first page it looks like this:

[image: Good Footer]

Why?

Comment: Have you seen question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196360/scrlttr2-make-second-page-footer-match-first-page-footer ? Possible duplicate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the header on the next pages use

```
\setkomavar{nexthead}{}
```

For the second problem use a `\parbox` inside `firstfoot`

```
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\usekomafont{pageheadfoot}\usekomafont{pagefoot}%
    \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{%
        \rule[3pt]{\linewidth}{.4pt} \\
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}% 
            Super Man\\
            Super Straße 30\\
            12345 Super Town
        \end{tabular}%
        \hfill
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
            Telefon: +49123456789\\
            super.man@gmail.com\\
        \end{tabular}%
        \hfill
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
            Bankverbindung: \\
            IBAN: DEXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XX\\
            BIC: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
        \end{tabular}%
    }%
}%
```

Note that firstfoot is a variable too and command `\firstfoot` is depreciated.

But the footer will still have a different position and width on the two pages:

[image]

---

**Pagestyle `plain` with package `scrlayer-scrpage`**

I would load package `scrlayer-scrpage` and use a plain page style on all pages.

The following examples uses the normal `plain` style. Only the footsepline is a bit shifted upwards.

```
\documentclass[
    firstfoot=false,%<- no first foot
    footheight=48pt
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\usepackage[footsepline,plainfootsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ModifyLayer[
  addvoffset=-1ex
]{plain.scrheadings.foot.above.line}% shift the footsepline up
\addtokomafont{pagefoot}{\normalfont\footnotesize}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot*{
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}% 
        Super Man\\
        Super Straße 30\\
        12345 Super Town
    \end{tabular}%
    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
        Telefon: +49123456789\\
        super.man@gmail.com\\
    \end{tabular}%
    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
        Bankverbindung: \\
        IBAN: DEXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XX\\
        BIC: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
    \end{tabular}%
}

\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\opening{\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{}% <- first pages will have pagestyle plain too

\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Name}
\setkomavar{firsthead}{It is still possible to set a firsthead.}% <- firsthead still works

\begin{letter}{Addr}
\opening{}
\Blindtext
\closing{}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But you can also change the vertical position and the width of the footer to your needs. Here is an example similar to the normal `firstfoot` settings.

```
\documentclass[
    firstfoot=false,%<- no first foot
    footheight=48pt
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\usepackage[footsepline,plainfootsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\KOMAoptions{footwidth=\useplength{firstfootwidth}}
\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{plain.scrheadings}{%
  \ifstrstart{#1}{plain.scrheadings.foot}{%
    \ModifyLayer[
      voffset={\useplength{firstfootvpos}-1em}
    ]{#1}
  }{}
}% shift the footer down
\ModifyLayer[
  addvoffset=-1ex
]{plain.scrheadings.foot.above.line}% shift the footsepline up
\addtokomafont{pagefoot}{\normalfont\footnotesize}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot*{
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}% 
        Super Man\\
        Super Straße 30\\
        12345 Super Town
    \end{tabular}%
    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
        Telefon: +49123456789\\
        super.man@gmail.com\\
    \end{tabular}%
    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
        Bankverbindung: \\
        IBAN: DEXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XX\\
        BIC: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
    \end{tabular}%
}

\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\opening{\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{}% <- first pages will have pagestyle plain too

\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Name}
\setkomavar{firsthead}{It is still possible to set a firsthead.}% <- firsthead still works

\begin{letter}{Addr}
\opening{}
\Blindtext
\closing{}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]